# Creating DynamodDB table on start of the localstack

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

Using Localstack with Dynamodb and need to create some tables by default on the start. However, I am getting the strange error that:

```
/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init.sh: is a directory
```

docker-compose config:

```
localstack:
    container_name: localstack
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "8010:8010"
    environment:
      - EDGE_PORT=8010
      - SERVICES=s3,dynamodb
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/.localstack/init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init.sh"
```

and the `init.sh` looks like:

```
awslocal dynamodb create-table \
   --table-name table-global \
   --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S \
   --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH \
   --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5
```

My stack:

- OS: MacOS Ventura
- Docker: v4.16.2

I have tried multiple options but it still does not work. I am not sure what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your issue by changing your `docker-compose.yml` to:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/init-aws.sh:/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/init-aws.sh"  # ready hook
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

The `init-aws.sh` looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
awslocal dynamodb create-table \
   --table-name table-global \
   --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S \
   --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH \
   --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5
```

Make sure to run `chmod +x init-aws.sh` on the file first.

I can validate this via the following command:

```bash
$ awslocal dynamodb list-tables
{
    "TableNames": [
        "table-global"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @harsh mishra, can you please also add how it got solved?

Comment: I just updated the `docker-compose.yml` to the latest configuration.